# Hibernate Search Mass Indexer custom query

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate Search for indexing and searching database records. For fast inserting of high amount of data, I have used JdbcTemplates for batch insert but when we do that, manually inserted data is not indexed anymore.

To overcome the problem I have used the Mass Indexer but it only accepts the entity name. Is it possible to index specific set of data using custom queries ? Say, it would be enough to index Contacts that has group id of X.

```
 ftm = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
 indexer = ftm.createIndexer(Contact.class)
    .batchSizeToLoadObjects(100)
    .cacheMode(CacheMode.NORMAL)
    .threadsToLoadObjects(2)
    .start();
```

P.S. [As per the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#manual-index-changes), creating custom mass indexers are possible but it does much more then I have expected and I'm not sure if it solves the problem. Other option could be selecting the records and adding to index manually but it's not feasible either.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the feature you are asking for is captured in [HSEARCH-499](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-499). the idea would be to work with a detached criteria query. However, as you can see from the status of the issue, it is not yet implemented. If you like you could revive the discussion.

One option which might speed up indexing is to use a [EntityIndexingIntercpetor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-mapping-indexinginterceptor). This allows to you to conditionally skip indexing of a given entity based on its state, eg a 'group id'. The index itself still needs to be loaded during the mass indexing processing, but depending on your model it could still speed up things, especially if your model is a bit more complex.